# Display setting 'size' not available in image settings modal

Tags: attachments, images

When editing a post in WP-Admin, I'm missing the *size* option in the display settings of attached images.

In this screenshot, the setting is available:

[image]

However, this is, what it looks in my page (in German):

[image]

I do have different image sizes (can see them in /wp-content/uploads). While I  do add image sizes in my custom theme, this happens independently of whether using my custom plugin and theme or default WP themes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you disabled plugins, switched to a default theme and tested again to rule those out? Are your images large enough? If they are too small for the built in sizes then they won't show.

Comment: I have the same issue. Anyone have some insights, Please?

Comment: Still have the same problem here